# How to debug emacs crashes on WSL2

Tags: linux, debugging, emacs, x11, wsl-2

I installed Emacs using the instructions on [this site](https://elecming.medium.com/the-ultimate-emacs-hacking-tutorial-in-windows-10-wsl-2-2fc4e9a899b0).  It was working fine for a while, but recently I have started experiencing frequent crashes.  E.g. every 20 minutes, Emacs shuts down without warning and without saving anything.  Sometimes, I get output printed in my terminal window, e.g.,

```
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Backtrace:
emacs(+0x146b12)[0x560737d11b12]
emacs(+0x48d1b)[0x560737c13d1b]
emacs(+0x49209)[0x560737c14209]
emacs(+0x48291)[0x560737c13291]
emacs(+0x48360)[0x560737c13360]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XIOError+0x52)[0x7fcd36f391a2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XEventsQueued+0x7d)[0x7fcd36f3685d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XPending+0x61)[0x7fcd36f28171]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x7020f)[0x7fcd376d920f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_prepare+0x19f)[0x7fcd370af72f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x520db)[0x7fcd370b00db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_pending+0x2c)[0x7fcd370b027c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_events_pending+0x12)[0x7fcd379bc402]
```

I am not 100% sure that the error message is correctly diagnosing the problem.  But if we assume that it is a correct diagnosis, how would I re-install Emacs so that it can recover from X disconnects?  Alternatively, how can I stop X from disconnecting?

Comment: Maybe try `/usr/bin/env XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1 emacs` from https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/69xm04/if_i_dont_run_emacs_as_root_it_instantly_crashes/

Comment: Have you tried to compile emacs with debugging symbols? AFAIK the GTK warning can be written even if it isn't the problem.

Comment: No idea if this will work on WSL, but you could try running configure like `./configure --with-x-toolkit=lucid` to use a different GUI toolkit.

Comment: [emacs.se] might be a better place to ask

Comment: This is super annoying. But while you're trying to fix it, let's not forget that you can also run emacs without X just in a terminal window (run as `emacs -nw`).

Comment: If there is an actual crash then please report it to Emacs developers: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. A crash always indicates a bug, of some kind.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions.  @TobiasFendin - can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by compiling with debugging symbols?  I have quite a bit of experience using debugging symbols with my own code, but I am not sure what to do in this case.  (i) what flags should I pass to make? (ii) what tools should I use to print relevant debugging information?  It would be nice if all I had to do was provide a simple switch to make and then automatically get more information printed to the terminal when emacs crashes.

Comment: @PhilipMaybank It's not clear how to enable debuggin when reading the ./configure --help, but I see two possible ways to do it. Set the environment variables CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS to "-g" (guessing, I havn't used WSL). The other possible way is to pass the --enable-profiling option to configure. If either of those is successful the backtrace would contain more useful information, such as function names.

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not find a solution to the specific issue I decided to stop using applications which require an X server with WSL2.  I have had a good experience with Emacs installed via Chocolatey - https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/Emacs .  I have also had good experiences with VS Code which seems to talk to WSL2 just as well as it talks to remote machines.

Comment: It's nice that you found a workaround for the problem but this "answer" won't help other people who have the same question. Perhaps you should unaccept it?